# RODBCext query parameters

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have sql query in R of this type:

```
    query <- "SELECT a.* FROM 
               ( (SELECT x,y,z FROM t1,t2,t3 where c1 = ? and c2 = ?) as b
                 LEFT JOIN
                 (SELECT x1,y1,z1 FROM t4, t5, t6 where c3 = ? and c4 = ?) as c
                  ON b.x = c.x1 ) as a"
```

I'm using RODBCext to connect and query database.
I do it like this:

```
    library(RODBCext)
    conHandle <- odbcConnect("dsn", uid="uid", pwd = "pwd", believeNRows = FALSE)
    parameters <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4) #values for parameters
    response <- sqlExecute(conHandle, query, parameters, fetch = TRUE)
```

I receive this error:

```
    Error in sqlExecute(conn, upit, parameters, fetch = TRUE) :
    [RODBCext] Error: Number of parameters in query do not match number of columns in data
```

Any help about this ??

Comment: Obviously this is going to be tough without an example. Can you verify step by step? ie run just the t1,t2,t3 statement with a 2 parameter data.frame?  I would also suggest you rationalise your sql statement to make it easier for you to debug as the example doesn't looke like it need subqueries.

Comment: Steph thanks ! My code showed here was ok. In my code I had parameters <- data.frame(c(v1, v2, v3, v4)) that was the problem. Code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this for anyone is looking after the fact:

According to the github for the rodbcext package: this error throws because number of params (number of question marks in your sql query) does not match the number of *columns* in the parameters dataframe. The mistake made was that wrapping a vector in data.frame results in n rows, not n columns.

```
if(nparams != LENGTH(data))
{
  error(_("Number of parameters does not match number of columns in provided data"));
  FreeHandleResources(thisHandle);
  return 100;
}
```